# how to add class to all children of the elements when children has different tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi I wandering how I can add class .draggable on each element in .edit div

This is my html:

```
  <div class="edit" >
       <h2> Some title </h2>
       <a> some link</a>
       <p> some paragraph </p>
       <ol> 
         <li> some list item</li>
         <li> some list item</li>
         <li> some list item</li>
       </ol>
    </div>
```

I don't really know how to grab each of the elements inside .edit and add class .draggable . The desired effect would be like that:

```
<div class="edit" >
   <h2 class="draggable" > Some title </h2>
   <a class="draggable"> some link</a>
   <p class="draggable"> some paragraph </p>
   <ol class="draggable"> 
     <li class="draggable">some list item</li>
     <li class="draggable"> some list item</li>
     <li class="draggable"> some list item</li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find each element with `*` selector and assign class `draggable`.
Try this:

```
$('.edit').find('*').addClass('draggable');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2hEJ/)

Comment: Glad to help you, accept the answer when you can to help other guys with the same problem @lipenco